# Browser compatible work-around instead of using .data()

Tags: jquery

Seems like certain browsers (Internet Explorer with Compatibility View `ON`) don't support the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) object, whats the next best thing to use?

```
$("#object").data('value','hi');
```

I was thinking I could apply classes to the object and use `hasClass()` but maybe there's a better way?  Would be better if it was as lightweight as possible (without using cookies)

Comment: Works fine for me - http://jsfiddle.net/n8Qyq/ . Just tested in IE w/ compatibility mode on.

Comment: What does it mean: "...don't support the .data() object" ??? What have you tested? Are there some errors? What is your context? - or better - make a jsfiddle where you have the same behavior!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly certain `data()` works even in that mode.

If it doesn't, add the correct meta tags into your `<head>` to force IE not to use broken mode.

Comment: I have the code `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />` in there as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use html5 data attributes.

```
$("#object").attr('data-val1','hi');
```

Comment: But that also isn't browser compatible.

Comment: @algorhythm - why isn't this compatible?

Comment: it's html5... sure, you can add an attribute to a DOM-element but if you try to do some html5 special things than it's possibly not browser compatible.

Comment: @algorhythm - Although part of the html5 spec, it isn't special. From John Resig - `I think what is most enticing about this whole specification is that you don't have to wait for any browser to implement anything in order to begin using it. By starting to use data- prefixes on your HTML metadata today you'll be safe in knowing that it'll continue to work well into the future.` It safely works even in IE6.

Comment: @mrtsherman: What!? That whole `prop` thing makes no sense. Your fiddle sets a value with `prop` and then tries to retrieve it using  `attr` which is just silly. If you use `attr` to set the values, you can retrieve them just fine. The only place where you might want to use `prop` to retrieve values is when interoperating with ancient JS code, but that's a rather special case.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen - yeah... I have no idea what I was thinking when I wrote that.